# Error after update to Meteor 1.3 - Handler with name 'onBeforeAction' already exists

Tags: meteor, updates, iron-router

My app has been working until I've updated it to Meteor 1.3. Now I get this error:

```
Exception in callback of async function: Error: Handler with name 'onBeforeAction' already exists.
at MiddlewareStack._create (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?hash=8a2aa73e86a32698fb9f60cea452e0ecb2e72b7f:190:13)
at MiddlewareStack.push (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?hash=8a2aa73e86a32698fb9f60cea452e0ecb2e72b7f:206:22)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?hash=8a2aa73e86a32698fb9f60cea452e0ecb2e72b7f:224:12
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?hash=8de51f9d86e95ae2ffee15a8db324a1decccba3e:139:11)
at MiddlewareStack.append (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?hash=8a2aa73e86a32698fb9f60cea452e0ecb2e72b7f:220:5)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?hash=8a2aa73e86a32698fb9f60cea452e0ecb2e72b7f:226:19
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?hash=8de51f9d86e95ae2ffee15a8db324a1decccba3e:139:11)
at MiddlewareStack.append (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron_middleware-stack.js?hash=8a2aa73e86a32698fb9f60cea452e0ecb2e72b7f:220:5)
```

The only places where I use `onBeforeAction` is in my iron-router route controllers. They're all in the same `router.js` file.

I define several route controllers, first an `ApplicationController` that extends `RouteController` and then various controllers that extend `ApplicationController`.

```
ApplicationController = RouteController.extend({
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    //some code
    this.next();
  }
});

SomeController = ApplicationController.extend({
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    //some code
    this.next();
  }
});
```

From the error message I'm unable to work out what is wrong or where to look for the problem.

Versions of packages mentioned in error message are:

```
iron:router@1.0.12
iron:middleware-stack@1.0.11
underscore@1.0.6
```

I'd really appreciate some pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of i would highly recommend you if it is possible to change your router and switch to `FlowRouter`. This is the official Meteor router by now, as stated here : [Meteor Guide](http://guide.meteor.com/routing.html)

Try this : `meteor update iron:middleware-stack`.

It seems that your problem is related to [this issue](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1513) and it has been fixed in `1.1.0` version.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @William Poussier. Updating `iron:middleware-stack` indeed solved the problem. I assumed all packages got updated to their latest version as part of the meteor update to version 1.3. Switching to FlowRouter is on the roadmap...